# I am new to GIS and QGIS and need some guidance for starting

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and GIS and i want to start learning it.
I am just confused where to start and what to learn first.
i want to do some small projects on QGIS
my degree is in Environment engineering, so it will be great if i can do some project related to my degree in QGIS.( I cant do field work as i am staying at home)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! As a new user, please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) - you should ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems you've come across. Something like an [online course](http://www.Udemy.com/QGIS) might be a good start for you.

Comment: You might even get some great help if you jump into our chat system here for this type of inquiry.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to check the excellent [QGIS Tutorials](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/introduction.html) website presented by a QGIS specialist "Ujaval Gandhi".

It's really clear and aimed at "level zero" people.
You can check the ***"Tutorials List"*** on the orange upper menu to check if there is a tutorial for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to take would be to look for a real project that you can volunteer to help with.

Try contacting local conservation-related organizations, such as:

- watershed groups
- local non-profits
- local environmental engineering firms
- town or county park districts
- state department of natural resources
- local office of The Nature Conservancy or Sierra Club
- bird watching groups, hiking clubs, etc

Ask if they have any simple mapping or GIS tasks that you can volunteer to help with.

Smaller organizations will be more likely to accept free help, but will have less of an idea what can reasonably be accomplished by a beginner to GIS. Larger organizations may have their own GIS experts on staff. This may mean that they know exactly what to ask for, and may even be able to provide you with training in the specific task. On the other hand, it may mean they don't need your help.

Here are a few examples of simple tasks. I recommend reading through some tutorials and  making your own list, so you know what you can offer to do.

- scanning and digitizing paper maps
- producing maps, eg for grant applications or reports

  - use categorized and rule-based symbologies to create color-coded maps
- processing field data collected by others (eg, GPS points, tracklogs, paper forms - yes, some people still collect data on paper)

Be sure not to promise more than you can deliver. If you're not sure if you can do what they're asking for, say so. Offer to investigate whether it's feasible, and get back to them within a reasonable time frame.

Keep in mind that many organizations use ArcGIS, not QGIS. Make sure that any output from your work is in a format that the organization can use. Don't expect them to be able to open and use your QGIS project file. If you're producing vector layers for them to use, put them in shapefile format unless otherwise requested. Be aware that QGIS cannot make layered pdfs - this is a relatively easy thing to produce in ArcGIS so people with some limited experience with GIS may expect this capability.